# How do I change an existing SharePoint web application to run the https protocol?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, https

We have a internet web application that published and running under http protocol, now we want to change to https .

- the existing web application running on Port 80
- its url is http://www.example.com

Here:

How I change a SharePoint web application to run HTTP to HTTPs protocol.

- Can I extend the existing web application (that is running on port 80)  to port 443?
- in which  Zone should I extend is extranet or internet?

note :this web application is internet faced application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure SSL to open your site through https:// instead of http://,

You may refer links once your web application is on internet zone you cannot extend it to internet zone again you need to extend it either to intranet, extranet or custom,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/01/21/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/03/configuring-a-sharepoint-website-to-allow-ssl-connections/

https://griffindocs.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/sharepoint-2013-how-to-add-ssl-to-a-web-application/

Comment: so here it not necessary to extend the web application to port 443  and to internet zone?

Comment: yes you can't do that.

Comment: now site opens when i type in browser https, but how i enable when i type example.com the site automatically opens with https://example.com

Answer (score 2):

- Can I extend the existing web application (that is running on port 80) to port 443? **Yes, but usually I just change the AAM to https and change the bindings in IIS to only use https if you are using IIS 5 or 6, you must "Require SSL".**
- in which Zone should I extend is extranet or internet? **Internet**

Comment: here site opens when i type https://example .com but 
how i enable by default it opens with https; for example when i type  example.com it should be  open with https://example.com

Comment: You are talking about a redirect. One way I know to do that is to custom code your 403.4 error page in IIS, add some javascript that will take the URL and redirect using https. Another way is to use the url rewrite module for iis. Here is an article about that: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/